# Query builder - bindings parameter order in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder, laravel-5

What I need it to create the query similar to this (the real query is much more complex):

```
SELECT * FROM person LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE name='abc') AS i ON i.person_id = person.person_id ORDER BY person.custom_1 DESC
```

I've created the following subquery:

```
$subQuery = \DB::table('invoice')->where('name','abc');
```

I have `person` table in my current `$model` so I do something like this:

```
 $model = $model->join(\DB::raw('(' . $subQuery->toSql().') as i', 'i.person_id,'=','person.person_id');
```

Now I have the following problem. `$model` is a Person model but it could have already be joined with other tables, conditions may have been also added etc. Also after the above query more conditions or joins may be applied.

The problem here are bindings.

I cannot simply run

```
 $model = $model->join(\DB::raw('(' . $subQuery->toSql().') as i', 'i.person_id,'=','person.person_id')->addBinding($subQuery->getBindings());
```

because those bindings will be added at the end and it will obviously won't work (bindings will be assigned in wrong order).

I cannot also use for example something like this:

```
$model->setBindings(array_merge($subQuery->getBindings(), $model->getBindings()));
```

because as I mentioned before I might have already joined `$model` with other tables. Also I cannot simply change subquery (it's quite complex indeed - here I put very simple version of it just to show the problem).

Question - is there any way to bind parameters from subquery to bind them in the right place?